# Deno: how to take care of accents when reading from windows terminal prompt?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, deno

I'm trying to use Deno to read an user input, but I'm having trouble with the encoding.

Here is my simple code from a Deno shell when I enter "áé":

```
> const a = prompt('Insert your character:');
Insert your character: áé
undefined
> a
"��"
```

My Windows command prompt has the encoding in CP-1252, that is very similar to ISO-8859-1.

How do I tell Deno the encoding of the string I inputed? Or how do I decode it from cp-1252?

Comment: It is currently unclear to me if this is an issue in Deno `prompt` or if it always using UTF-8 is intended and desired behavior. I've started a discussion that you might want to follow/join to learn more with me: [Should prompt always use UTF-8 even when the connected console may be using a different encoding? · Discussion #11773 · denoland/deno](https://github.com/denoland/deno/discussions/11773)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible this behavior will change in future versions of Deno (see [New prompt method gets confused when receiving special characters as input [ã] · Issue #8239 · denoland/deno](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/8239)) but for now if you need to use an encoding other than the one used by [`prompt`](https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#prompt) (which currently appears to always be UTF-8) then you can directly use [`Deno.stdin`](https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#Deno.stdin) which implements [`Deno.Reader`](https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#Deno.Reader).

e.g. Using [`readLines`](https://doc.deno.land/https/deno.land/std/io/bufio.ts#readLines) you can specify the encoding:

```js
import { readLines } from "https://deno.land/std@0.105.0/io/bufio.ts";

async function prompt(
  message = "Prompt",
  { encoding }: { encoding?: string } = {}
) {
  await Deno.stdout.write(new TextEncoder().encode(`${message} `));
  const { value } = await readLines(Deno.stdin, { encoding }).next();
  return <string>value || null;
}

const a = await prompt("Insert your character:", { encoding: "windows-1252" });
console.log(a);
```